# Gulp - Returning errors for browserSync

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to set up gulp to automatically refresh projects when I save changes via tutorials online.

It keeps throwing back errors every time I initiate "gulp serve"

**Versions**

```
node version - v12.13.0
npm version - 6.13.0
gulp version - 3.9.1
```

My **gulpfile.js** code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('css', function () {
 gulp.src('./styles/**/*.css')
  .pipe(uglifycss({
   "maxLineLen": 80,
   "uglyComments": true
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
}); 

gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

browserSync.init({
    server: "./app"
});

gulp.watch("app/scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src('js/*js')
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('js-watch', ['js'], function (done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});

gulp.task('default', ['js'], function () {
     browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
gulp.watch("js/*.js", ['js-watch']);
});
```

My **package.json** code:

```
{
  "name": "fifteen-projects",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Project files",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
  "gulp-uglifycss": "^1.1.0"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
  "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
  "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
  "node-sass": "^4.13.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/MarvinBrereton-creator/fifteen-projects.git"
  },
  "author": "Marvin Brereton",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/MarvinBrereton-creator/fifteen-projects/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/MarvinBrereton-creator/fifteen-projects#readme"
  }
```

When I initiate "**gulp serve**" in cmd inside the project folder where gulp is located it throws back:

```
fs.js:27const { Math, Object } = primordials;
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
at fs.js:27:26
at req_ (C:\Users\kk\Documents\GitHub\fifteen-projects\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
at Object.req [as require] (C:\Users\kk\Documents\GitHub\fifteen-    projects\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kk\Documents\GitHub\fifteen-projects\node_modules\vinyl-   fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
```

I think the problems are coming from the Node_modules folder as the errors are coming from there whenever I try to initiate gulpfile.js

- Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way was to use the inbuilt extension (Hot Reload) within VsCode. Gulp was outdated for what was needed.